# Plotly: How to determine direction of confusion matrix?

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, confusion-matrix, plotly-python

I'm using Plotly for plotting the below confusion matrix:

```
cf_matrix= confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
print(cf_matrix)

[[1595  545 2240]
 [ 788  722 2870]
 [ 181  118 4081]]

import plotly.figure_factory as ff
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(cf_matrix)
fig.show()
```

but for some reason the plot is in the wrong  direction "starting from the down left corner" as can be seen below:

Any workaround to get it the Matrix the usual direction and also show the X and Y axis?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The answer:

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis = dict(categoryorder = 'category descending'))
```

#### Some details in your example:

If the data you've presented is in fact your dataset, then you haven't specified any names. You can do that with, for example, `names = list('ABC')`, and then do:

```
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z, x = names, y = names)
```

In order to change the order of the heatmap, you can do:

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis = dict(categoryorder = 'category descending'))
```

#### Plot:

[image]

If this was not *exactly* the way you wanted it to appear, you can change the `xaxis` in the same way. Also, other options for categoryorder are:

```
['trace', 'category ascending', 'category descending',
'array', 'total ascending', 'total descending', 'min
ascending', 'min descending', 'max ascending', 'max
descending', 'sum ascending', 'sum descending', 'mean
ascending', 'mean descending', 'median ascending', 'median
descending']
```

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

z = [[1595, 545, 2240],
 [ 788,   722,  2870],
 [ 181,   118,  4081]]

names = list('ABC')

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z, x = names, y = names)
fig.update_layout(yaxis = dict(categoryorder = 'category descending'))
fig.show()
```

Comment: marvellous! thank you so much vestland :)